# SharedPreference to remember the checkbox is visible and checked

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a checkbox that is invisible, however when I click on the menu item the checkbox is visible. What should the SharedPreferences look like if the checkbox is checked, and if I leave the app and return to the app to keep the checkbox visible. Now, when I leave the app and the checkbox is checked, and when I return to the app the checkbox is invisible and did not remember that the checkbox was checked.

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/my_check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Save Audio file"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



private CheckBox my_check;

    // onCreate
    addListenerOnSaveAudio();


    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.save_audio:
    saveAudio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }


public void addListenerOnSaveAudio() {

    my_check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.my_check);

    my_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                // My code
            } else {
                saveAudio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: does anyone have an idea how to do this code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc for [sharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java) and how to use it.
You need to save the state of your checkbox when someone clicks your menu to do that you can use:

```java
// in onCreate
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "NAME OF YOUR CHOICE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

CheckBox checkBox = findViewById(R.id.my_check);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
if(preferences.contains("my_check") && preferences.getBoolean("my_check",false) == true) {
   checkBox.setChecked(true);
}else {
    checkBox.setChecked(false);

}
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
            editor.putBoolean("my_check", true);
            editor.apply();
        }else{
            editor.putBoolean("my_check", false);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it'll not work this way. Can you check and gradually write this code as in my example, thanksss

Comment: I do not have a report because I tried another variant, but I would like you to write the code specifically.

Comment: use my code and write a full variant, it might be useful to someone else, thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated my code there was a typo. Other than that, you can't expect people to do all the work. Being a developer means searching and trying until it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean state;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private Checkbox my_check;
public void addListenerOnSaveAudio() {
   //Instance for save state of my_check
   sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("name_preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   my_check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.my_check);
   // If my check not exist by default is false else true
   state = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("my_check", false);
   my_check.setChecked(state);
   my_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //When do click in my_check will change state in preferences and when open your app is apply changes in view.
            sharedPreferences.edit()
              .putBoolean("my_check",isChecked);
            if (isChecked) {
              // My code
            } else {
               saveAudio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onCheckedChanged()` to register a listener to your `checkBox`, and then save its check status into shared preference.

And get the shared preference value each time you launch your app, i.e. in `onCreate()` method

So modify your activity's `onCreate()` and your `addListenerOnSaveAudio()` as below

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private CheckBox my_check;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

        my_check = findViewById(R.id.my_check);

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isChecked = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("checkValue", false); // default value is false
        my_check.setChecked(isChecked);


        addListenerOnSaveAudio();


    }


    public void addListenerOnSaveAudio() {

        my_check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("checkValue", isChecked);
                editor.apply();
                if (!isChecked)
                    saveAudio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```